# Why is the upload-release-asset github action failing

Tags: github, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have a yml file automating the building and uploading of our 2d unity project. the build is uploaded and functions fine as an artifact, however when I try to make an official release with that artifact as the release asset, it only includes the source code of my repository and I get the error:

```
/build/Galactic.zip doesn't match any files
Galactic.zip doesn't match any files
```

This is our yml file:

```
name: Building and Testing 

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - cd-testing
      - main
      - build-fix
      - unity-cd
      
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build my project  ✨
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checkout
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          lfs: true

      # Cache
      - name: Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: PlatformerStealthGame/Library
          key: Library-${{ hashFiles('Assets/**', 'Packages/**', 'ProjectSettings/**') }}
          restore-keys: |
            Library-PlatformerStealthGame-
            Library-
            
      # Build
      - name: Build project
        uses: game-ci/unity-builder@v2
        env:
          UNITY_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.UNITY_EMAIL }}
          UNITY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.UNITY_PASSWORD }}
          UNITY_SERIAL: ${{ secrets.UNITY_SERIAL }}
        with:
          projectPath: PlatformerStealthGame
          targetPlatform: StandaloneWindows
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Galactic
          path: /build

      # Unity Return License
      - name: Unity - Return License
        uses: game-ci/unity-return-license@v2.0.0      

      # Test
      - name: Run tests
        uses: game-ci/unity-test-runner@v2
        env:
          UNITY_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.UNITY_EMAIL }}
          UNITY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.UNITY_PASSWORD }}
          UNITY_SERIAL: ${{ secrets.UNITY_SERIAL }}
        with:
          projectPath: PlatformerStealthGame
          githubToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}     
          # targetPlatform: WebGL     
          
      # Unity Return License
      - name: Unity - Return License
        uses: game-ci/unity-return-license@v2.0.0          
          
      # Release
      - name: Automatic Releases
        uses: marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@v1.2.1
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: "latest"
          prerelease: false
          title: "Development Build"
          files: |
             /build/Galactic.zip
             Galactic.zip
             *.zip
            
      # Unity Return License
      - name: Unity - Return License
        uses: game-ci/unity-return-license@v2.0.0
```

i have changed the name of the release so that it is unique every time with the commit name but this didn't fix the error.

Comment: Your error seems to indicate that your tag_name isn't unique.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a release tag in the workflow that uses the workflow ref as the tag name.

```
- name: Automatic Releases
  id: create_release
  uses: actions/create-release@v1
  with:
    tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
```

But because of your workflow trigger events, ref will be a branch name

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - cd-testing
      - main
      - build-fix
```

Refs on a git repository must be unique, so you cannot create tags that use existing branch names. Instead you could try generating a unique version number for each release tag.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tip! I have since changed my code, and am now getting a `/build/Galactic.zip doesn't match any files` code. I will update the post to include my up-to-date code.